# How to type installed keyboard language? (installed the input language)

Tags: linux-mint, ibus

I have installed ibus language, below the desktop icon, it did show option to select chinese or english keyboard, however when i type it still show english letter only.

What should i do to type chinese characters in it?

OS: Linux Mint 
Language trying to type: Chinese

Update
Steps I did:

1. Went to 'Language Settings'
2. Clicked 'Add Support for ibus' and installed the list packages
3. Went to Startup Applications to add command as 'ibus-daemon'
4. Went to Ibus Preferences, selected input method and added 'chinese - googlepyin'
5. Selected the icon icon bar bottom right, and selected 'Chinese'
6. Tested on libreoffice writer, but typed words still remain english letter. ( the chinese language is still selected)

Reference:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ibus

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain exactly what you installed and how. Have you checked under settings -> keyboard ?

Comment: I have edited, please let me know if i need to provide more information or screenshot, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

`ibus-preferences` does not appear to control your input method

You should go to `gnome-settings` via `Settings` -> `Region & Language` and add the correct **Input Sources**, in your case, `Chinese (GooglePinyin)`

A language input indicator should appear at the status bar where you should be able to select the language input